# Linux shell script command - gzip

Tags: csv, gzip, gunzip

I am having one shell script in Linux in which the output will be generated in .csv format.

At the end of the script i am making this .csv to .gz format to reduce the space on my machine. 
The file which is generated comes in this format Output_04-07-2015.csv

The command which i have written to make it zip is:-gzip Output_*.csv

But i am facing an issue that if the file already exists, then it should make the new file with that reported time stamp.
Can anyone help me with it.?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to just overwrite the file if it already exists, gzip has a -f flag for it.

`gzip -f Output_*.csv`

What the -f flag does is *forcefully* create the gzip file, and overwrite whatever existing zip file there might already be.

Have a look at the man pages by typing `man gzip` or even [this link](http://water.usgs.gov/GIS/gzip/gzip_doc.txt) for many other options.

If instead you want to do it more elegantly, you could check out and see if shell commands for your script work for you or not. But that would differ depending on what shell you have, bash, cshell, etc.